# Laravel 5 composer update not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using Laravel version 5.2 and Jenssegers MongoDB. I installed both and working fine but I have to use any other library and made changes in composer.json after that use command **composer update**. After using this command automatically Jenssegers MongoDB file removed. I don't know why this happen. After composer update why Jenssegers MongoDB file removed automatically? Please suggest me how to handel this?

My composer.json file

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/common_helper.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you  installed jessenger mongodb via terminal?

Comment: Yes, I install jessenger mongodb via terminal. For installation use this
[link](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

Comment: can you please post your composer.json file? Make sure that file is writable.

Comment: In my project i using AdminLTE themes [link](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel)

Comment: @RaviHirani made changes in question and also post composer.json

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115785/discussion-between-user3663481-and-ravi-hirani).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this `"jenssegers/mongodb": "*",` line in your composer.json file:-

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel": "2.*",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "*",
},
```

And add the service provider in `config/app.php`

```
Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\PasswordResetServiceProvider,
```

then go to project root directory in terminal and run command `composer update` .

In model file, you need to add below line at the top,

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
```

Reference :- [documentation](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

Comment: get error after run command composer update
" Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Session\SessionServiceProvider' not found in /vendor/laravel/framework
  /src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146"

Comment: @user3663481: Please check my answer again. you need to dd servideProvider in config/app.php file

Answer (score 0):

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

you can stop scripts run

Comment: what is the actual problem behind it ?